# How to use cordova-diagnostic-plugin with meteor?

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I was using Cordova diagnostic plugin-https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin , added it using meteor add cordova:cordova.plugins.diagnostic@1.1.0 , i wrote the code like below as mentioned in plugin github readme

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
        console.log("Location is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
    }, function(error){
        console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
    });
 }
 }
```

But i am getting error as shown below

> Uncaught TypeError:Cannot read Property 'diagnostic' of undefined

Any help on how to use this plugin in meteor.

Comment: check the list of plugins, if your plugin is installed. If it is that it must be conflicting with some other plugin causing your Meteor plugin not working.

Comment: i am using these meteor pakakages and cordova plugin cordova:cordova.plugins.diagnostic  1.1.0
fortawesome:fontawesome             4.4.0 
iron:router                         1.0.9  
meteor-platform                     1.2.2 
natestrauser:animate-css            3.2.6  
vinaypuppal:framework7              0.0.1+(local package)             
@MurtazaKhursheedHussain

Comment: There must be something which is conflicting with your plugin which is why it is not loading. try removing every plugin one by one and check which one is causing conflict

Comment: only one cordova plugin i am using ,rest of the plugins like device,file,splashscreen etc are provided by Meteor itself, i think they cant be removed...@Murtaza Khursheed Hussain

Comment: I think within `Meteor.isCordova` you are safe to call directly `diagnostic.isLocationEnabled()`

Comment: I tried what u said but this time i got this error  Uncaught ReferenceError: diagnostic is not defined
@RaduChiriac

Comment: It's strange, I don't really see why. Are you sure "cordova.plugins.diagnostic@1.1.0" in your `.meteor/cordova-plugins` ?

Comment: Yes it is present in .meteor/local/cordova-build/plugins/ of my project directory.@RaduChiriac

Comment: I think problem is because of meteor build process, the plugin started working fine after i delete cordova-build folder and rebuild the cordova app again.

Comment: Thank You @RaduChiriac  and 'MurtazaKhursheedHussain' for your suggestions.